Can't type/click into a text area anymore due to jQuery but can't see what's causing it
I'm learning jQuery at the moment via a Front End Web Development online course. I have a text area on my webpage but since using jQuery I can't type or click into the text area. I know the problem is the jQuery code as when I deleted the link to JavaScript in HTML the text area works fine. I don't know what specifically is causing the problem within jQuery. I'll put the code below.
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('text');

      console.log($('.submenu a').first().text());
      console.log($('.submenu a').last().text());


        $(document).on('contextmenu', function(){
          return false;
        });

        $(document).on('mousedown', function (event){
          event.preventDefault();


          if(event.which == 3){

            $('.hidden').removeClass('shown');

            if ($(event.target).is('img')){
                $('.saveimg, .newtab').addClass('shown');
            } else if ($(event.target).is('a')){
                $('.newtab').addClass('shown');
            }

            console.log(event.pageY, event.pageX);

            $('#context').css({
                top: event.pageY,
                left: event.pageX
            });

            $('#context').fadeIn();
                return false;

          }

            $('#context').fadeOut();
        })


        $('a[href="https://google.com"]').on('click', function(event){

        console.log("Linking to Google?");

        return true;
        });





    $('[data-trigger="dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function(){
      var submenu = $(this).parent().find('.submenu');
      submenu.fadeIn(350);

      $('.profile-menu').on('mouseleave', function(){
          submenu.fadeOut(350);
      });

    });


    $('#prepend, #append, #replace').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        var el = $(e.currentTarget);
        var action = el.attr('id');
        var content = $('.text').val();

        if(action == "prepend"){
            console.log("Prepending...");
            $('#main').prepend(content);

        }
        else if(action == "append"){
            console.log("Appending...");
            $('#main').append(content);

        }
        else if(action == "replace"){
            console.log("Replacing...");
            $('#main').html(content);
        };

        $('.text').val('');


    });



    $('textarea').focusin(function(){
        console.log("Focused in on the textarea");
    });




});


Can you please try to comment this line out $(document).on('mousedown', function (event){           event.preventDefault();. I mean just the event.preventDefault();.

Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do read the [tour] and [ask] pages.  Please also see [mcve].  Ideally we'd like to be able to recreate your issue by using the code provided.  The issue may be with your HTML (or at least how jquery interacts with it) and having your HTML/css means we can see the issue without having to infer / recreate it.  In addition, try to keep the code you provided limited to just the relevant parts.  Quite often, in determining what is relevant, you'll find the issue yourself.

Please also review your tags - [tag:java] is not in anyway related to [tag:javascript].   Is the issue related to [tag:atom-editor]? There's no indication that this is even used.

As noted above, the issue appears to be that all mousedown (thus all clicks) are blocked.   This shouldn't stop you from using tab to tab to the textarea and type, just stop you from selecting it with the mouse.

You have an event set to happen on a mousedown over the whole document, and inside that event handler function you have a call to preventDefault() which prevents other events from firing. Since <textarea> is inside document, the mousedown event for the document is fired instead of the textarea event. Check this fiddle for more information:


$(document).ready(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('text');

    console.log($('.submenu a').first().text());
    console.log($('.submenu a').last().text());


    $(document).on('contextmenu', function () {
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('mousedown', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#events_feedback").html("Wow! I clicked on the document!");
    })


    $('a[href="https://google.com"]').on('click', function (event) {

        console.log("Linking to Google?");

        return true;
    });


    $('[data-trigger="dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function () {
        var submenu = $(this).parent().find('.submenu');
        submenu.fadeIn(350);

        $('.profile-menu').on('mouseleave', function () {
            submenu.fadeOut(350);
        });

    });


    $('#prepend, #append, #replace').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var el = $(e.currentTarget);
        var action = el.attr('id');
        var content = $('.text').val();

        if (action == "prepend") {
            console.log("Prepending...");
            $('#main').prepend(content);

        } else if (action == "append") {
            console.log("Appending...");
            $('#main').append(content);

        } else if (action == "replace") {
            console.log("Replacing...");
            $('#main').html(content);
        }
        ;

        $('.text').val('');


    });


    $('textarea').focusin(function () {
        console.log("Focused in on the textarea");
    });


});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<p id="events_feedback">This is a test feedback from JS events.</p>

<textarea id="my_textarea"></textarea>

</body>
</html>



Note that if you comment event.preventDefault() on $(document).on('mousedown'...) the textarea event starts working.
